# How to update Jtable immediately or automtically when I press a button

Tags: java, swing

I have created a `JTable` with some information about formula 1 racing car drivers. The below code is for the `JTable`

```
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import java.awt.event.*;


public class Test1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {
JButton button;
Test1() {
    //setBounds(100, 100, 500, 400);
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    button = new JButton();
    
    //button.setBounds(50, 50, 20, 10);s
    button.setText("Random Race");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JTable table = new JTable(new Model1Data()); 
   
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 400);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    panel.add(button);
    
    //add(new J
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //this.add(button);
    pack();
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Formula1ChampionsManager d= new Formula1ChampionsManager();
    d.button();
}
}
```

This is the code for the `Model1Data`. This is the code for the table to update its cells.

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Model1Data extends AbstractTableModel implements ChampionsManager {

String colNames[] = { "Name", "Team", "No of first Places", "Total Points" };
Class<?> colClasses[] = { String.class, String.class, Integer.class, Integer.class };

public int getRowCount() {
    return myDrivers.size();
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return colNames.length;
}

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (columnIndex == 0) {
        return myDrivers.get(rowIndex).getName();
    }
    if (columnIndex == 1) {
        return myDrivers.get(rowIndex).getTeam();
    }
    if (columnIndex == 2) {
        return myDrivers.get(rowIndex).getfirstPlace();
    }
    if (columnIndex == 3) {
        return myDrivers.get(rowIndex).totalPoints();
    }
    return null;
}

public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    return colNames[columnIndex];
}

public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return colClasses[columnIndex];
}

public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return false;
}

public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (columnIndex == 0) {
        myDrivers.get(rowIndex).setName((String) aValue);
    }
    if (columnIndex == 1) {
        myDrivers.get(rowIndex).setTeam((String) aValue);
    }
    if (columnIndex == 2) {
        myDrivers.get(rowIndex).setfirstPlace((Integer) aValue);
    }
    if (columnIndex == 3) {
        myDrivers.get(rowIndex).settotalPoints((Integer) aValue);
    }
    
    //fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    
}
}
```

This what the table GUI looks like [Table GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmhJz.png). When I click the button the values for *No of first places* and *Total Points* are changed randomly. But the table doesn't get updated with the values. If I pull on the side of the frame it gets updated. How do I get it to update when I click the button?

Comment: If you're updating the model, it should update automatically.  If it's not you might need to fire off model.fireTableDataChanged()

Comment: If Ryan's suggestion does not work, try to revalidate or repaint the table component. You can do that programmatically by calling the appropriate methods.

Comment: @Ryan where should I add it to

Comment: @John In your button function immediately after you update the cell values.  Alternatively, you could call `model.fireTableCellUpdated()` if you know the row and column.  Oh, and you should be doing all of this inside a `SwingWorker`

Comment: @Ryan Actually, changes to model objects and calls to fireTableCellUpdated should *not* be done in a SwingWorker or in any thread other than the event dispatch thread.  Obviously long-running tasks should be, but the eventual changes to the model should be in the thread which reads the model, namely the event dispatch thread.

Comment: @Ryan _If you're updating the model, it should update automatically_ correct - but _If it's not you might need to fire off model.fireTableDataChanged() ... In your button function immediately after you update the cell values_ (merged 2 comments) is utterly wrong: the firing has to be done by the __model__, not by client code. Fix the model, if it doesn't

Comment: @corneliu _try to revalidate or repaint the table component_ that's utterly __wrong__: if the table doesn't update itself, then there's an error in the model - fix it instead of smearing over it

Comment: why did you comment calling of the fireXX methods? That's what you __have to__ do to make your model behave correctly when subclassing AbstractTableModel ..

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 0):

The `JTable` listens for changes in the `TableModel`. Hence class `AbstractTableModel` has methods such as `fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex)` (which you commented out in your code - why?). If you override method `setValueAt` then you need to call that method, otherwise the `JTable` will not update when its data is changed. I'm guessing that changing the size of the `JFrame` causes a repaint of the `JTable` which causes the `JTable` to reload the data from its model (but I could be wrong).

Your class `Model1Data` should extend [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), rather than `AbstractTableModel`, since that class already contains all the functionality you require. The only method that class `Model1Data` needs to override is [getColumnClass](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnClass(int)) (which it already does). You also need to override at least one constructor. Since you didn't post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'm guessing that [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,int)) may be appropriate. Hence the code for class `Model1Data` should be:

```java
public class Model1Data extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel {
    Class<?> colClasses[] = { String.class, String.class, Integer.class, Integer.class };

    public Model1Data(Object[] columnNames, int rowCount) {
        super(columnNames, rowCount);
    }

    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return colClasses[columnIndex];
    }
}
```

And in class `Test1` (which does not need to extend `JFrame`, by the way) you can create the [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) like so:

```java
JTable table = new JTable(new Model1Data(new String[]{ "Name", "Team", "No of first Places", "Total Points" }, 0));
```

### Edit

Here's my take on what you are trying to do. The below code can be copied as is, compiled and run. Just click on the *Random Race* button and the data in the `JTable` will update.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Test1 {
    private JTable  table;

    private void buildAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTable(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text, int mnemonic, ActionListener listener) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        return button;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton("Random Race", KeyEvent.VK_R, this::randomRace));
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JScrollPane createTable() {
        table = new JTable(new Model1Data());
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    /**
     * Simulates a race and randomly determines placings of the drivers and assigns appropriate
     * points scores.
     * 
     * @param event - encapsulates button press event
     */
    private void randomRace(ActionEvent event) {
        Formula1ChampionsManager.simulate();
        TableModel tm = table.getModel();
        if (tm instanceof Model1Data) {
            Model1Data model = (Model1Data) tm;
            model.setRowCount(0);
            model.init();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Test1().buildAndDisplayGui();
        });
    }
}

class Model1Data extends DefaultTableModel {
    private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {"Name", "Team", "No of first Places", "Total Points"};

    public Model1Data() {
        super(COLUMN_NAMES, 0);
        init();
    }

    public void addDriver(F1Driver driver) {
        addRow(new Object[]{driver.getName(),
                            driver.getTeam(),
                            driver.getFirstPlace(),
                            driver.getTotalPoints()});
    }

    public void init() {
        Formula1ChampionsManager.getDrivers()
                                .stream()
                                .forEach(this::addDriver);
    }
}

class Formula1ChampionsManager {
    private static List<F1Driver>  drivers;

    static {
        drivers = List.of(new F1Driver("Lewis Hamilton", F1Teams.MERCEDES),
                          new F1Driver("Max Verstappen",F1Teams.RED_BULL),
                          new F1Driver("Charles Leclerc",F1Teams.FERRARI),
                          new F1Driver("Lando Norris",F1Teams.MCLAREN),
                          new F1Driver("Fernando Alonso",F1Teams.ALPINE),
                          new F1Driver("Pierre Gasly",F1Teams.ALPHATAURI),
                          new F1Driver("Sebastian Vettel",F1Teams.ASTON_MARTIN),
                          new F1Driver("Nicholas Latifi",F1Teams.WILLIAMS),
                          new F1Driver("Valtteri Bottas",F1Teams.ALFA_ROMEO),
                          new F1Driver("Mick Schumacher",F1Teams.HAAS));
    }

    public static List<F1Driver> getDrivers() {
        return drivers;
    }

    public static void simulate() {
        List<F1Driver> result = new ArrayList<>(drivers);
        Collections.shuffle(result);
        F1Driver first = result.get(0);
        first.update(F1Driver.FIRST);
        F1Driver second = result.get(1);
        second.update(F1Driver.SECOND);
        F1Driver third = result.get(2);
        third.update(F1Driver.THIRD);
        F1Driver fourth = result.get(3);
        fourth.update(F1Driver.FOURTH);
        F1Driver fifth = result.get(4);
        fifth.update(F1Driver.FIFTH);
        F1Driver sixth = result.get(5);
        sixth.update(F1Driver.SIXTH);
        F1Driver seventh = result.get(6);
        seventh.update(F1Driver.SEVENTH);
        F1Driver eighth = result.get(7);
        eighth.update(F1Driver.EIGHTH);
        F1Driver ninth = result.get(8);
        ninth.update(F1Driver.NINTH);
        F1Driver tenth = result.get(9);
        tenth.update(F1Driver.TENTH);
    }
}

enum F1Teams {
    MERCEDES("Mercedes"),
    RED_BULL("Red Bull"),
    FERRARI("Ferrari"),
    MCLAREN("McLaren"),
    ALPINE("Alpine"),
    ALPHATAURI("AlphaTauri"),
    ASTON_MARTIN("Aston Martin"),
    WILLIAMS("Williams"),
    ALFA_ROMEO("Alfa Romeo"),
    HAAS("Haas");

    private String  name;

    private F1Teams(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Enum
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

class F1Driver {
    public static final int  FIRST = 25;
    public static final int  SECOND = 18;
    public static final int  THIRD = 15;
    public static final int  FOURTH = 12;
    public static final int  FIFTH = 10;
    public static final int  SIXTH = 8;
    public static final int  SEVENTH = 6;
    public static final int  EIGHTH = 4;
    public static final int  NINTH = 2;
    public static final int  TENTH = 1;

    private String  name;
    private F1Teams  team;
    private int  firstPlace;
    private int  totalPoints;

    public F1Driver(String name, F1Teams team) {
        this(name, team, 0, 0);
    }

    public F1Driver(String name, F1Teams team, int firstPlace, int totalPoints) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name, "Missing name.");
        this.name = name;
        this.team = team;
        this.firstPlace = firstPlace;
        this.totalPoints = totalPoints;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public F1Teams getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(F1Teams team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    public int getFirstPlace() {
        return firstPlace;
    }

    public void setFirstPlace(int firstPlace) {
        this.firstPlace = firstPlace;
    }

    public int getTotalPoints() {
        return totalPoints;
    }

    public void setTotalPoints(int totalPoints) {
        this.totalPoints = totalPoints;
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Object
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean equal = this == obj;
        if (!equal) {
            if (obj instanceof F1Driver) {
                F1Driver other = (F1Driver) obj;
                equal = name != null             &&
                        name.equals(other.name)  &&
                        team == other.team;
            }
        }
        return equal;
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Object
    public int hashCode() {
        return (String.valueOf(name) + String.valueOf(team)).hashCode();
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Object
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s [%s] %d [%d]", name, team, totalPoints, firstPlace);
    }

    public void update(int points) {
        totalPoints += points;
        if (points == FIRST) {
            firstPlace++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how it looks when I run the above code.

[image: animated GIF of running app]

Comment: No.  He's doing his model correctly.  `DefaultTableModel` should only be used for very basic data.  He's doing it right by extending `AbstractTableModel`

Comment: @Ryan the question is not clear enough to decide which is the best class to extend, DefaultTableModel might just be okay - but: when starting from AbstractTableModel (as you suggest) the modifying methods __have to__ fire the appropriate notifications